# Spring MVC - Two dynamic pages in one single page

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have two pages -

home page - it has two dropdown lists which are loaded dynamically from the server. It has search button.

On clicking the search button  will open which again has search button will open to new window.

I need to have both the pages in one single page.

Can u please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far and what's the part where you're having problems, see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for help on how to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. Using jquery and ajax, I am able to achieve this thing.

Using "div" tag helps to identify and two search buttons one each page is calling separate jquery methods.

Best Regards
Arpan